# Zeppelin change port not updated

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am changing zeppelin defect port from 8080 to 8180 in the config file "zeppelin-site.xml.template" file . After restarting the server still zeppelin is still connected to 8080 port only . Please advise how to connect to 8180 port

Answer (score 1):

zeppelin-site.xml.template file is just for reference. Copy zeppelin-site.xml.template file to zeppelin-site.xml and make the changes.